# Gui next and Prev Buttons with JPA entities

Tags: java, jpa, user-interface, jdialog

I have this Entity called **Users** which basically is mapping of table **Users** in my database which holds **empid**-*reference to employee* **username**, **password**, **level**
.  The entity also impliment the basic methods **getters** and **setters** .
 So now i have created a dialog form and i want to impliment the previous and next button and have to reflect what is in the entity at that given moment. please advise me how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

> *"So now i have created a dialog form and i want to impliment the previous and next button and have to reflect what is in the entity at that given moment."*

I would use a `CardLayout`. You can layer panels on top of each other, and call the `next()` or `previous()` method on the layout the show the next and previous panel.

See [Using CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) tutorial

1. Add a `JPanel` with a `CardLayout` to the `JDialog`

   ```
   CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();
   JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel(layout);
   ```
2. Add the other `JPanel` layers to the main panel, giving a *"call name"* to each of those panels

   ```
   JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
   JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
   JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
   panel.add(panel1, "panel 1");
   panel.add(panel2, "panel 2");
   panel.add(panel3, "panel 3");
   ```
3. In the `actionPerformed` of the `nextButton` and `previousButton` just call the `next()` and `previous()` methods of the layout

   ```
   nextButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       layout.next(panel);
   }
   previousButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       layout.previous(panel);
   }
   ```